# How to attach a rigidbody to a camera(bullet physics)?

Tags: c++, opengl, game-physics, bulletphysics

I've been working on a project using OpenGL and Bullet physics, but can't seem to figure out how to move the rigidbody to the camera. I've tried setting the motion state repeatedly and translating it upon key presses and both of these methods do not work. This is my camera movement code.(I have commented out both methods.)

```
       void CameraUpdateLoop()
{
    xpos = 0;
    ypos = 0;

    deltatime = glfwGetTime() - prevtime;
    glfwGetCursorPos(window,&xpos,&ypos);
    //  cout << xpos << " " << ypos << endl;
    glfwSetCursorPos(window,800/2,600/2);
    hangle += mousesens * deltatime *  (400 - xpos);
    vangle += mousesens * deltatime *  (300 - ypos);
    direction = glm::vec3(cos(vangle)* sin(hangle),sin(vangle),cos(vangle)* cos(hangle));
    right = glm::vec3(sin(hangle - 3.14f/2.0f),0,cos(hangle - 3.14f/2.0f));
    up = glm::vec3(glm::cross(right,direction));
    if(glfwGetKey(window,GLFW_KEY_W) == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        position += direction * deltatime * speed;

       // rigidbody->translate(btVector3(direction.x,direction.y,direction.z) * deltatime * speed);

    }
    if(glfwGetKey(window,GLFW_KEY_S) == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        position -= direction * deltatime * speed;

       // rigidbody->translate(-(btVector3(direction.x,direction.y,direction.z) * deltatime * speed));
    }
    if(glfwGetKey(window,GLFW_KEY_D) == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        position += right * deltatime * speed;

        //rigidbody->translate(btVector3(right.x,right.y,right.z) * deltatime * speed);
    }
    if(glfwGetKey(window,GLFW_KEY_A) == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        position -= right * deltatime * speed;


        //rigidbody->translate(-(btVector3(right.x,right.y,right.z) * deltatime * speed));
    }
    btTransform output;
    //fallMotionState = new btDefaultMotionState(btTransform(btQuaternion(0, 0, 0, 1), btVector3(position.x,position.y, position.z)));
    //rigidbody->setMotionState(fallMotionState);
    rigidbody->getMotionState()->getWorldTransform(output);
    cout << output.getOrigin().getZ() << endl;

    if(vangle < -90.0f)
    {
        vangle = -90.0f;
    }
    if(vangle > 90.0f)
    {
        vangle = 90.0f;
    }
    // cout << vangle << endl;
    // cout << hangle << endl;
    ProjectionMatrix = glm::perspective(initfov,4.0f/3.0f,0.1f,100.0f);
    ViewMatrix= (glm::lookAt(position,position+direction,up));
    prevtime = glfwGetTime();
}
```

The issue is that no manifolds are produced with each tick even though getting the origin with motion states usually produces correct output.

```
static void test (btDynamicsWorld *world, btScalar timeStep)
{
    int numManifolds = world->getDispatcher()->getNumManifolds();
    if(numManifolds >= 1)
    {
        cout << "collision" << endl;
        glClearColor(0.0,0.7,0.8,1.0);
    }
    else if(numManifolds < 1)
    {
       glClearColor(0.0,0.3,0.8,1.0);
    }
```